# Rounding integers nearest 10 in Presto

Tags: sql, rounding, presto

I am trying to round integers to the nearest 10 in Presto SQL, so 1999 would become 2000,
2134 would become 2130, and so on.

I have tried `ROUND(x, -2)` and `ROUND(x, -1)` but this formulation does not work.  `FLOOR()` in this case is not an appropriate choice.

What is the workaround in Presto SQL?

Comment: What version of Presto are you running? I tested in version 332 and `ROUND(x, -1)` produces the expected value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
select round(x / 10.0) * 10
```